# How to properly manage a vector of void pointers

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector, void-pointers

**First, some background:**

I'm working on a project which requires me to simulate interactions between objects that can be thought of as polygons (usually triangles or quadrilaterals, almost certainly fewer than seven sides), each side of which is composed of the radius of two circles with a variable (and possibly zero) number of 'rivers' of various constant widths passing between them, and out of the polygon through some other side. As these rivers and circles and their widths (and the positions of the circles) are specified at runtime, one of these polygons with N sides and M rivers running through it can be completely described by an array of N+2M pointers, each referring to the relevant rivers/circles, starting from an arbitrary corner of the polygon and passing around (in principal, since rivers can't overlap, they should be specifiable with less data, but in practice I'm not sure how to implement that).

I was originally programming this in Python, but quickly found that for more complex arrangements performance was unacceptably slow. In porting this over to C++ (chosen because of its portability and compatibility with SDL, which I'm using to render the result once optimization is complete) I am at somewhat of a loss as to how to deal with the polygon structure.

The obvious thing to do is to make a class for them, but as C++ lacks even runtime-sized arrays or multi-type arrays, the only way to do this would be with a ludicrously cumbersome set of vectors describing the list of circles, rivers, and their relative placement, or else an even more cumbersome 'edge' class of some kind. Rather than this, it seems like the better option is to use a much simpler, though still annoying, vector of void pointers, each pointing to the rivers/circles as described above.

**Now, the question:**

If I am correct, the proper way to handle the relevant memory allocations here with the minimum amount of confusion (not saying much...) is something like this:

```
int doStuffWithPolygons(){
    std::vector<std::vector<void *>> polygons;
    while(/*some circles aren't assigned a polygon*/){
        std::vector<void *> polygon;
        void *start = &/*next circle that has not yet been assigned a polygon*/;
        void *lastcircle = start;
        void *nextcircle;
        nextcircle = &/*next circle to put into the polygon*/;
        while(nextcircle != start){
            polygon.push_back(lastcircle);
            std::vector<River *> rivers = /*list of rivers between last circle and next circle*/;
            for(unsigned i = 0; i < rivers.size(); i++){
                polygon.push_back(rivers[i]);
            }
            lastcircle = nextcircle;
            nextcircle = &/*next circle to put into the polygon*/;
        }
        polygons.push_back(polygon);
    }

    int score = 0;
    //do whatever you're going to do to evaluate the polygons here
    return score;
}

int main(){
    int bestscore = 0;
    std::vector<int> bestarrangement; //contains position of each circle
    std::vector<int> currentarrangement = /*whatever arbitrary starting arrangement is appropriate*/;
    while(/*not done evaluating polygon configurations*/){
        //fiddle with current arrangement a bit
        int currentscore = doStuffWithPolygons();
        if(currentscore > bestscore){
            bestscore = currentscore;
            bestarrangement = currentarrangement;
        }
    }

    //somehow report what the best arrangement is

    return 0;
}
```

If I properly understand how this stuff is handled, I shouldn't need any delete or .clear() calls because everything goes out of scope after the function call. Am I correct about this? Also, is there any part of the above that is needlessly complex, or else is insufficiently complex? Am I right in thinking that this is as simple as C++ will let me make it, or is there some way to avoid some of the roundabout construction?

And if you're response is going to be something like 'don't use void pointers' or 'just make a polygon class', unless you can explain how it will make the problem **simpler**, save yourself the trouble. I am the only one who will ever see this code, so I don't care about adhering to best practices. If I forget how/why I did something and it causes me problems later, that's my own fault for insufficiently documenting it, not a reason to have written it differently.

**edit**
Since at least one person asked, here's my original python, handling the polygon creation/evaluation part of the process:

```
#lots of setup stuff, such as the Circle and River classes

def evaluateArrangement(circles, rivers, tree, arrangement): #circles, rivers contain all the circles, rivers to be placed. tree is a class describing which rivers go between which circles, unrelated to the problem at hand. arrangement contains (x,y) position of the circles in the current arrangement.
    polygons = []
    unassignedCircles = range(len(circles))
    while unassignedCircles:
        polygon = []
        start = unassignedCircles[0]
        lastcircle = start
        lastlastcircle = start
        nextcircle = getNearest(start,arrangement)
        unassignedCircles.pop(start)
        unassignedCircles.pop(nextcircle)
        while(not nextcircle = start):
            polygon += [lastcircle]
            polygon += getRiversBetween(tree, lastcircle,nextcircle)
            lastlastcircle = lastcircle
            lastcircle = nextcircle;
            nextcircle = getNearest(lastcircle,arrangement,lastlastcircle) #the last argument here guarantees that the new nextcircle is not the same as the last lastcircle, which it otherwise would have been guaranteed to be.
            unassignedCircles.pop(nextcircle)
        polygons += [polygon]
    return EvaluatePolygons(polygons,circles,rivers) #defined outside.
```

Comment: Why void pointers? Why not a vector of pointers of some base class type with virtual methods?

Comment: If you allocate anything on the heap, it will *not* be deallocated when you go out of scope. You have to wrap it in some sort of manager object which iterates through and `delete`s anything you allocated. As a rule of thumb, any allocation call through `new` should be deallocated through a `delete` call when you are done

Comment: Probably the biggest reason not to use void pointers is because you deny the compiler the ability catch errors that you might make with pointer assignment.

Comment: Maybe you could show the python code you are trying to port.  There should be a way to do a pretty direct conversion.

Comment: @Joel Cornett: Would a vector of shared or unique pointers work in terms of automatic garbage collection?

Comment: @Joel Cornett- I'll admit that defining a new base class had not occurred to me. I'm not sure I'll do it, since it doesn't seem to be any neater than using void pointers is under the circumstances and adds otherwise unnecessary clutter to the overall structure. I don't think your reason for not using void pointers applies in my case as they only come into play here and in the evaluation code, which only uses them to get their perimeter and area.

Comment: @Joel Cornett- regarding your second comment, I'm not sure I properly understand what it is you are saying I must delete, since I do not at any point use 'new' (unless I do so implicitly- I'm not very familiar with the syntax). Do I need to manually delete the vectors alone, the pointers alone, or both?

Comment: Are you using new to create those rivers and cycles? If not, you also don't  need to delete them manually.

Comment: If rivers and cycles don't have anything in common void* is almost as good as a poinzer to base class. The big question is how you are going to use zhose vectors. By eliminating the type, you are potentially slowing dow your program as you deny the compiler information it can use to optimize it. Also you have to store some additional information, that tells you later, whether the void pointer points to a circle or a river

Comment: @MikeMB- I am using new to create them, but they are also sticking around until the whole thing's run it's course. There are a couple steps I left out at the end for being irrelevant to the question, and deletion of the rivers and circles is part of that. My question is solely about the polygon constructions I'm using as part of the evaluation process, as contained within the doStuffWithPolygons function.

Comment: And you can avoid the inner for loop, by storing the pointers directly in the polygon.

Comment: The polygons themselges must not be deleted via calling delete.

Comment: @MikeMB- sorry, your second comment was posted while I was typing. Circles have a radius, 'weight' which is relevant to how the program can shuffle them around, a string that describes how distorted they are (doesn't play into anything I'm doing here) and a few functions that describe stuff irrelevant to the optimization. Rivers have width and an array of integers describing the path they take, which is only relevant when drawing the final, optimized layout. I describe how i use the vector in my comment to Joel above.

Comment: @MikeMB- what do you mean by 'storing the pointers in the polygon'? I can only get a vector containing the pointers from a separate class (the tree class I reference in my python), so is there a way to combine the vectors that I am not aware of?

Comment: Never use void pointers for any application logic. Use two separate containers rather than sticking two unrelated datatypes into the same container. If you for some strange reason can't do that, use `boost::any` or two polymorphic classes with a common base or a union.

Comment: @n.m.: What is the advantage of creating polymorphic classes without any common interface compared to using void pointers? I'm certainly not recommending using void pointers, but creating a class hierarchy for no other reason than "I want to store pointers to them in a single container" is equally bad. Casting to and from void* is absolutely well defined behavior (as long as it is the same type). Boost::any may be solution, but it is quite slow, as it uses RTTI and would trigger a dynamic memory allocation for every single pointer

Comment: There is no point in creating polymorphic classes without any common interface. Refactor so that there is common interface. Casting from `void*` requires you to know the target type in advance which means you must keep that information elsewhere (error-prone).

Comment: Gotta say, I'm loving how many peoples' solution to 'I can't figure out how to do this' is 'don't do this, why would anyone want to do this?'.

Comment: @n.m The 'strange reason' I can't use two separate containers rather than sticking two unrelated datatypes into the same container is the same reason arrays of strings still have an integer length. And your second solution seems to be 'oh, so rivers and circles have nothing in common? Well, just change them so that they do!' because following C++ conventions is far more important than actually accomplishing anything, I guess. If I make an error in casting void pointers, that is because I messed up the casting, not because void pointers are evil.

Comment: "is the same reason arrays of strings still have an integer length.". I don't get it. "just change them so that they do!" No you don't do that. You change your program structure such that you don't deal with circles and rivers directly. You deal with, say, geometry handlers. Geometry handlers handle geometry, that would be their commonality. River handlers handle rivers and circle handlers handle circles.

Comment: "If I make an error in casting void pointers, that is because I messed up the casting". If youd don't use void pointers, you don't have a chance to mess up casting, so there's one less thing to go wrong. That's why we have high-level languages.

Comment: @n.m- last comment for me in this chain, because we're not getting anywhere. Saying not to use void pointers so you don't mess up casting is like saying not to drive because you might get in a car crash. Any reasonable choice involves evaluating the risk involved with a particular action. And given the choice between rewriting my entire codebase and rethinking the very fundamentals of everything it represents or risking an easily diagnosed and trivial to fix problem later down the line if I get particularly careless, I'm going to choose the latter.

Comment: If you already have void pointers throughout your large codebase you may have to live with them. This doean't mean using void pointers was a wise design decision and you should do it again in a new project. I'm not sure how your car driving analogy is supposed to work. Void pointers are not the only vehicle that can move from point A to point B, there are many others that are better.

Answer (score 0):

Void as template argument must be lower case. Other than that it should work, but I also recommend using a base class for that. With a smart pointer you can let the system handle all the memory management.

Comment: Well, now I'm really confused. If what I've already got, void pointers and all, should work, then what memory management is there for the system to handle? I still need to make all the pointers and manually add them to the vector, and if you're right I don't need to manually delete them, so what actual benefit is there to making a whole new, otherwise pointless base class?